# unable to retrieve data from respective table zf2

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework2

While using this, this will gives an resultset object successfully

```
$goals = $this->getGoalTable()->listgoal($userid);
$goals->current();
return new ViewModel(array(
'paginator' => $goals,
));
```

but while retrieving this, i am getting blank! no data and no errors also

```
<?php foreach($paginator as $row){ ?>
    <?php print_r($row);    // this is giving its own model's data of controller but not my goal tables data  ?>
       <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($row->name);   // getting blank values here  ?>
       <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($row->coach_email);  // getting blank values here ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in controller itself -

```
$goals = $this->getGoalTable()->listgoal($userid);
$goals->current();

print_r($goals); //Its an object with single array.
exit();
```

and check if you get any values.

Comment: print_r($row); is giving me only its own models data of controller but not goal tables data, i mean my controller name is user, so its giving me user tables data values only

Comment: Even the `print_r($goals);` gives you the same result?

Comment: Can you please provide the `getGoalTable()` and `listgoal()` function code in the question?